# iOS simulator giving error "DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator"

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I've been getting the "DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator" error.  It has worked fine for weeks, even for a while this morning, but now has just stopped working.  No new updates or installs.  Xcode 7.3, iOS 10.11.4, Mac Book Pro.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Steps I've taken:

- restart simulator
- restart Xcode
- look at the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200318/dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-dtxconnection-with-simulator), followed the suggestion to click "OK" and wait
- look at the issue [here](http://codegur.com/27159833/xcode-6-is-unable-to-find-simulator-device-and-times-out) and followed the instructions

Still can't get the error message to go away.  Based on the requests for log files in the other issues, I'm adding what I think is the relevant section of the system log file:

```html
13:36:05 g4-2 ibtoold[8320]: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
13:36:05 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
13:36:05 g4-2 ibtoold[8320]: Invalid Connection ID 0
13:36:09 g4-2 lsd[362]: LaunchServices: Could not store lsd-identifiers file at /private/var/db/lsd/com.apple.lsdschemes.plist
13:36:10 g4-2 loginwindow[100]: -[SFLListManager(ServiceReplyProtocol) notifyChanges:toListWithIdentifier:] Notified of item changes to list with identifier com.apple.LSSharedFileList.RecentApplications
13:36:14 g4-2 WindowServer[220]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Simulator" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
13:36:16 g4-2 lsd[211]: LaunchServices: Could not store lsd-identifiers file at /private/var/db/lsd/com.apple.lsdschemes.plist
13:36:17 g4-2 WindowServer[220]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Simulator" after 3.73 seconds [0.27fps] (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds [1.00fps])
13:36:17 g4-2 nehelper[8329]: objc[8329]: Class NEHelperSystemProviderManager is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/NetworkExtension.framework/Versions/A/NetworkExtension and /usr/libexec/nehelper. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
13:36:18 g4-2 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[8272]: Could not register service com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport: Failed to lookup com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport: 0x44e
13:36:31 g4-2 BezelServices 255.10[100]: ASSERTION FAILED: dvcAddrRef != ((void *)0) -[DriverServices getDeviceAddress:] line: 2789
13:36:31 g4-2 syslogd[46]: ASL Sender Statistics
13:36:31 g4-2 BezelServices 255.10[100]: ASSERTION FAILED: dvcAddrRef != ((void *)0) -[DriverServices getDeviceAddress:] line: 2789
13:36:55 g4-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.jdibackup.ZipCloud.notify[8365]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
13:37:25 g4-2 usernoted[384]: Failed to validate application at (null) -67071
13:37:25 g4-2 usernoted[384]: dealloc (null)
13:39:29 g4-2 sandboxd[7919] ([419]): storeaccountd(419) deny file-write-create /Users/robin/Library/Caches/com.apple.spotlight
13:39:42 g4-2 sandboxd[7919] ([419]): storeaccountd(419) deny file-write-create /Users/robin/Library/Caches/com.apple.spotlight
 Call location:
13:39:49 g4-2 DivXUpdate[8405]: 0   CarbonCore                          0x99d04e3d ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 135
13:39:49 g4-2 DivXUpdate[8405]: 1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x93bd783f _dispatch_client_callout + 50
13:39:49 g4-2 DivXUpdate[8405]: 2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x93bd771b dispatch_once_f + 78
13:39:49 g4-2 DivXUpdate[8405]: 3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x93bd8fa5 dispatch_once + 31
13:39:49 g4-2 DivXUpdate[8405]: 4   CarbonCore                          0x99c808e1 _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 1047
13:39:49 g4-2 DivXUpdate[8405]: 5   CarbonCore                          0x99c8008a Gestalt + 154
13:39:49 g4-2 DivXUpdate[8405]: 6   QtCore                              0x003dedeb _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii + 59
13:39:57 g4-2 lsd[362]: LaunchServices: Could not store lsd-identifiers file at /private/var/db/lsd/com.apple.lsdschemes.plist
13:40:35 g4-2 WindowServer[220]: Untrusted client (pid=8406) attempted to set debug options.
13:40:42 g4-2 plugin-container[8406]: WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.4 instead of 10.11.4. This is not a bug in Gestalt -- it is a documented limitation. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number.
 Call location:
13:40:43 g4-2 plugin-container[8406]: 0   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8d4d86df ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 113
13:40:43 g4-2 plugin-container[8406]: 1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff954fc40b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
13:40:43 g4-2 plugin-container[8406]: 2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff954fc303 dispatch_once_f + 67
13:40:43 g4-2 plugin-container[8406]: 3   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8d464fbc _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 987
13:40:43 g4-2 plugin-container[8406]: 4   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8d4647d0 Gestalt + 139
13:40:43 g4-2 plugin-container[8406]: 5   XUL                                 0x0000000102a3e9e0 vpx_reset_mmx_state + 629243
13:40:48 g4-2 networkd[179]: __42+[NETAWDManager sharedAWDServerConnection]_block_invoke Created AWD server connection 0x7fd07a625620 with component ID 0x29
13:40:49 g4-2 networkd[179]: -[NETAWDManager reportStats:metricID:] server 0x7fd07a625620, container 0x7fd07a705450, metrid 2686985, successfully reported:
 <AWDLibnetcoreStatsReport: 0x7fd07a637d40> {
     mbufStatisticsReport =     {
         mbuf16KBTotal = 27;
         mbuf256BTotal = 1696;
         mbuf2KBTotal = 1362;
         mbuf4KBTotal = 201;
         mbufDrainCount = 0;
         mbufMemReleased = 0;
         sockAtMBLimit = 0;
         sockMBcnt = 5992;
     };
     networkdStatisticsReport =     {
         fallbackConnectionCount = 0;
         totalConnectionCount = 589;
         totalSuccessfulConnectionCount = 585;
     };
     reportReason = 1;
 }
13:40:58 g4-2 G2MUpdate[8409]: G2MUpdate activated at 2016-05-02 17:40:56 +0000
13:41:11 g4-2 G2MUpdate[8409]: G2MUpdate: Cleaning up unused endpoints.
13:41:11 g4-2 G2MUpdate[8409]: Removing unused builds...
13:42:19 g4-2 kernel[0]: nspace-handler-set-snapshot-time: 1462210941
13:42:19 g4-2 com.apple.mtmd[224]: Set snapshot time: 2016-05-02 13:42:21 -0400 (current time: 2016-05-02 13:42:19 -0400)
13:44:00 g4-2 com.apple.SecurityServer[84]: Killing auth hosts
13:44:00 g4-2 com.apple.SecurityServer[84]: Session 100233 destroyed
13:44:01 g4-2 com.apple.SecurityServer[84]: Session 100266 created
13:44:03 g4-2 Xcode[8268]: +[DTServiceHubClient localConnectionWithAuthorization:returningServerPid:]: failed to establish connection with DTServiceHub service '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Resources/DTServiceHub'
13:44:04 g4-2 Xcode[8268]:  iPhoneSimulator: Unable to connect to "com.apple.instruments.deviceservice.lockdown" (Error Domain=DTServiceHubClient Code=-11 "unable to contact local DTServiceHub to bless simulator connection" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unable to contact local DTServiceHub to bless simulator connection})
13:44:08 g4-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dt.instruments.dtarbiter.xpc[8423]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
13:45:26 g4-2 mds[64]: (ImportServer.Normal:1721) Ignoring blacklisted Spotlight importer plugin:/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/SourceCode.mdimporter uuid:548A3091-3C5D-498A-A329-B532A6C896BB version:1586
13:45:57 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
```

And the Core Simulator log:

```html
13:36:11  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: A new peer connected.
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for CoreSimulator directory to be created. (fd=8)
13:36:11  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Notification subscription for set: /Users/robin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/AppleInternal/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for AppleInternal directory to be created. (fd=9)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for DeviceTypes in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles. (fd=10)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profile bundles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes. (fd=12)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for Runtimes in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles. (fd=11)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Scanning for new device type profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profile bundles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes. (fd=13)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-1080p : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/Apple TV 1080p.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Scanning for new runtime profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Runtime bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-9-2 : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/tvOS 9.2.simruntime
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/AppleInternal/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for AppleInternal directory to be created. (fd=10)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for CoreSimulator directory to be created. (fd=11)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/AppleInternal/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for AppleInternal directory to be created. (fd=14)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for DeviceTypes in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles. (fd=15)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profile bundles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes. (fd=17)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for Runtimes in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles. (fd=16)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Scanning for new device type profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profile bundles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes. (fd=18)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2 : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPad 2.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air-2 : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPad Air 2.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPad Air.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPad Pro.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPad Retina.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPhone 4s.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5 : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPhone 5.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPhone 5s.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPhone 6 Plus.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6 : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPhone 6.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s-Plus : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPhone 6s Plus.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPhone 6s.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Scanning for new runtime profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Runtime bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3 : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.3.simruntime
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/AppleInternal/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for AppleInternal directory to be created. (fd=15)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for CoreSimulator directory to be created. (fd=16)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/AppleInternal/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for AppleInternal directory to be created. (fd=19)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for CoreSimulator directory to be created. (fd=20)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/AppleInternal/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for AppleInternal directory to be created. (fd=21)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for DeviceTypes in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles. (fd=22)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profile bundles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes. (fd=24)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for Runtimes in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles. (fd=23)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Scanning for new device type profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profile bundles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes. (fd=25)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Unknown principal class for bundle: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/Apple Watch - 38mm.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-38mm : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/Apple Watch - 38mm.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Unknown principal class for bundle: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/Apple Watch - 42mm.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Device type bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-42mm : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/Apple Watch - 42mm.simdevicetype
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Scanning for new runtime profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Runtime bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-2-2 : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/watchOS 2.2.simruntime
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/AppleInternal/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for AppleInternal directory to be created. (fd=22)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for DeviceTypes in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles. (fd=23)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for Runtimes in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles. (fd=26)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profile bundles in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes. (fd=27)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Scanning for new runtime profiles in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Runtime bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-1 : /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Runtime bundle found com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-4 : /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.4.simruntime
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /AppleInternal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for AppleInternal directory to be created. (fd=26)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Info>: Monitoring for new profiles in /Users/robin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Currently watching for Profiles directory to be created. (fd=28)
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: New device pair (6139EC22-B857-4862-973D-2DC383D2F821 => (D9296D97-4A42-4EF0-9ED4-9D937ACD48D0, 45CA5E1C-8419-4456-8A9F-DAF4EC2E1283)) in set /Users/robin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: New device pair (9C1F917D-159B-401A-8ACC-53C079014729 => (026C4005-1106-4CD9-9CA5-28F45CDFC8AF, 151B2BE9-4563-4711-9A58-9D8B9F0A3156)) in set /Users/robin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
13:36:11  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: bootAsyncWithOptions: {
     env =     {
         "IPHONE_TVOUT_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES" = "/Users/robin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/151B2BE9-4563-4711-9A58-9D8B9F0A3156/data/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/com.apple.iphonesimulator/extended_display.plist";
         "SIMULATOR_EXTENDED_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES" = "/Users/robin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/151B2BE9-4563-4711-9A58-9D8B9F0A3156/data/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/com.apple.iphonesimulator/extended_display.plist";
     };
 }
13:36:11  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: bootAsyncWithOptions: {
     deathPort = "<NSMachPort: 0x7fd112c2f8e0>";
     env =     {
         "IPHONE_TVOUT_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES" = "/Users/robin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/151B2BE9-4563-4711-9A58-9D8B9F0A3156/data/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/com.apple.iphonesimulator/extended_display.plist";
         "SIMULATOR_EXTENDED_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES" = "/Users/robin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/151B2BE9-4563-4711-9A58-9D8B9F0A3156/data/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/com.apple.iphonesimulator/extended_display.plist";
     };
 }
13:36:11  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Relaying notification: {
     device = "SimDevice : iPhone 6s Plus (151B2BE9-4563-4711-9A58-9D8B9F0A3156) : state={ Booting } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s-Plus } runtime={ SimRuntime : 9.3 (13E230) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3 }";
     "new_state" = 2;
     notification = "device_state";
     "prev_state" = 1;
     "xpc_notification" = "<OS_xpc_dictionary: <dictionary: 0x7fd112d42110> { count = 4, contents =\n\t\"state\" => <uint64: 0x7fd112d39050>: 2\n\t\"udid\" => <string: 0x7fd112d3f890> { length = 36, contents = \"151B2BE9-4563-4711-9A58-9D8B9F0A3156\" }\n\t\"set_path\" => <string: 0x7fd112d4b040> { length = 52, contents = \"/Users/robin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices\" }\n\t\"notification\" => <string: 0x7fd112d53ad0> { length = 12, contents = \"device_state\" }\n}>";
 }
13:36:11  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registered notification proxy handler for com.apple.system.clock_set -> com.apple.system.clock_set
13:36:11  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registered notification proxy handler for com.apple.system.thermalpressurelevel -> com.apple.system.thermalpressurelevel
13:36:11  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Setting initial notification state com.apple.system.thermalpressurelevel: 0
13:36:11  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registering service com.apple.PowerManagement.control with launchd_sim
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registering service com.apple.SystemConfiguration.configd_host with launchd_sim
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registering service com.apple.audio.coreaudiod with launchd_sim
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registering service com.apple.SystemConfiguration.PPPController with launchd_sim
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registering service com.apple.audio.audiohald with launchd_sim
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport: Failed to lookup com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport: 0x44e
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registering service com.apple.FSEvents with launchd_sim
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registering service com.apple.SystemConfiguration.configd with launchd_sim
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registering service IndigoHIDRegistrationPort with launchd_sim
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registering service com.apple.iphonesimulator.upstream with launchd_sim
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registering service PurpleFBServer with launchd_sim
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Registering service PurpleFBTVOutServer with launchd_sim
13:36:18  com.apple.iphonesimulator[8324] <Debug>: Created deathTriggerPort: <NSMachPort: 0x7ff819c3bc40>
13:36:18  CoreSimulatorService[8272] <Debug>: Relaying notification: {
     device = "SimDevice : iPhone 6s Plus (151B2BE9-4563-4711-9A58-9D8B9F0A3156) : state={ Booted } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s-Plus } runtime={ SimRuntime : 9.3 (13E230) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3 }";
     "new_state" = 3;
     notification = "device_state";
     "prev_state" = 2;
     "xpc_notification" = "<OS_xpc_dictionary: <dictionary: 0x7fd112c2f150> { count = 4, contents =\n\t\"state\" => <uint64: 0x7fd112c2f710>: 3\n\t\"udid\" => <string: 0x7fd112c2ed00> { length = 36, contents = \"151B2BE9-4563-4711-9A58-9D8B9F0A3156\" }\n\t\"set_path\" => <string: 0x7fd112c3c310> { length = 52, contents = \"/Users/robin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices\" }\n\t\"notification\" => <string: 0x7fd112c4eb50> { length = 12, contents = \"device_state\" }\n}>";
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200318/dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-dtxconnection-with-simulator)

Comment: As I mentioned above, I looked at that issue and followed the instructions found there, but it did not help.  The issue eventually went away on its own, but I lost several days of work.

Comment: I'm having the same problem after updating from El capitan + Xcode 8 to Seirra + Xcode 8.2.1 The only solution I've found so far is a complete restart of my mac...