# iOS Simimulator error DTAssetProviderService could not start and restart not helping

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7.3

I recently upgraded my MBP to El Capitan and XCode 7.3.1 but when I try to run my project in Simulator I get "DTAssetProviderService could not start" error. I've tried clean, restart both tools, and restart my machine, but the issue persists.  In /var/log/system.log here is the pertinent logs around that time:

```
May 18 10:00:38 lsacco-mac kernel[0]: com.apple.dt.Xco[6277] triggered unnest of range 0x7fff92800000->0x7fff92a00000 of DYLD shared region in VM map 0x3ab4b61dbef
May 18 10:00:44 lsacco-mac kernel[0]: xpcproxy[6300] triggered unnest of range 0x7fff8f200000->0x7fff8f400000 of DYLD shared region in VM map 0x3ab4b61dbe725e15. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
May 18 10:00:44 lsacco-mac kernel[0]: AMFI: com.apple.dt.ins(pid 6300) - [deny-mmap] mapped executable file has no team identifier in its signature: /usr/local/lib/libwep
May 18 10:00:44 lsacco-mac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dt.instruments.dtarbiter.xpc[6300]): Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
May 18 10:00:44 lsacco-mac DTServiceHub[6299]: dtarbiter XPC call failure (register_client_with_singleton): (os/kern) failure
May 18 10:00:44 lsacco-mac Xcode[6059]: +[DTServiceHubClient localConnectionWithAuthorization:returningServerPid:]: failed to establish connection with DTServiceHub service '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Resources/DTServiceHub'
May 18 10:00:44 lsacco-mac Xcode[6059]:  iPhoneSimulator: Unable to connect to "com.apple.instruments.deviceservice.lockdown" (Error Domain=DTServiceHubClient Code=-11 "unable to contact local DTServiceHub to bless simulator connection" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unable to contact local DTServiceHub to bless simulator connection})
May 18 10:00:44 lsacco-mac kernel[0]: xpcproxy[6301] triggered unnest of range 0x7fff8f200000->0x7fff8f400000 of DYLD shared region in VM map 0x3ab4b61dd3a83ab5. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
May 18 10:00:44 lsacco-mac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ReportCrash[6301]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash
May 18 10:00:44 lsacco-mac ReportCrash[6301]: Saved crash report for com.apple.dt.instruments.dtarbiter[6300] version ??? to /Users/lsacco/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/com.apple.dt.instruments.dtarbiter_2016-05-18-100044_lsacco-mac.crash
```

The crash file simply had this:

```
Process:               com.apple.dt.instruments.dtarbiter [6300]
Path:                  /private/var/run/*/com.apple.dt.instruments.dtarbiter
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.instruments.dtarbiter
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
User ID:               0

Date/Time:             2016-05-18 10:00:44.332 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        D0D71B50-8DA8-77BD-34D9-F97A39EE7F20

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1F71874E-C351-4020-AAF2-D5B9BE9992B9

Time Awake Since Boot: 5400 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep
  Referenced from: /private/var/run/*/com.apple.dt.instruments.dtarbiter
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/libwep: mmap() error 1 at address=0x10E599000, size=0x00008000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /usr/local/lib/libwep

Binary Images:
    0x7fff6ccff000 -     0x7fff6cd3625f  dyld (360.22) <A468D85E-D8D6-3461-8C99-49D3B9ACFC63> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8721b000 -     0x7fff87586657  libobjc.A.dylib (680) <D55D5807-1FBE-32A5-9105-44D7AFE68C27> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff92f8c000 -     0x7fff93402fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1258.1) <943A1383-DA6A-3DC0-ABCD-D9AEB3D0D34D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff93c2e000 -     0x7fff93f82fff  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1259) <71A9D3A0-0B1F-3E3A-86F3-1486365A6EF2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff9cb24000 -     0x7fff9cb25ffb  libSystem.B.dylib (1226.10.1) <C5D09FE1-CC70-383E-AC27-18602F2EDEC4> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200318/dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-dtxconnection-with-simulator) references several fixes relating to restarting and cleaning different things but none worked for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be an issue with having WebSense installed by my IT department. It is known to inject libraries into other processes such as Simulator. Once removed, it was working again.