# DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator iOS 9

Tags: ios9, simulator

When I'm trying to build my app I'm getting an error DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator 'iPhone 6s'. Check the systems logs for errors.

[image: Screenshot]

Why am I getting this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200318/dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-dtxconnection-with-simulator)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this error will happen after `Xcode` is updated to version `7.3` . For solving this error the easy way is:

First of all -  Quit both `Xcode` & simulator

second, delete Derived data:  Right click on finder and select "Go To Folder" Type `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` in textbox. It will redirect you to `DerivedData` folder. Delete all folders which are  inside it.

Now finally close the project and Relaunch `Xcode` and Run your project again.

Answer (score 0):

When you see this error, Just click "Ok".and agains Project Run it its working fine.
Or
Quit Simulator and reset contest setting.