# Xcode 7 or 8 issue with Pods, can't run at all

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, cocoapods

Getting this error for pods in Xcode when trying to run app:

`error: A cryptographic verification failure has occurred.`

- Tried reinstalling Pods/repo
- Reinstalling Xcode(s)
- Also doesn't run on simulators:

[image: DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator]

Also, running Sierra at the moment (yes, I know).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200318/dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-dtxconnection-with-simulator)

Comment: I am facing this alet always while running an app each time a new simulator is being launched. I am able to launch application after "reset content and settings" of simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got mine working now!! Not really sure what I did, at all, but I just deleted the Xcode 8 .app entirely and then I redownloaded it, opened up my project in it, did a pod install and pod update, and it's running in the simulator just like normal! Not sure what I did at all, but redownloading is worth a try, it is in fact possible to fix.

Comment: Likely the only relevant thing in there is the fact that you did it a second time.  The device will boot faster the second time compared to the first.  This is consistent with all the other reports indicating a timeout in setting up that connection.

Comment: @conner-owen reinstall Xcode 8 with same results unfortunately. Were you able to get it working exclusively on sim or also a device?

Comment: It works for me now on both the simulator and actual devices, iOS 9.3 and 10. Not sure at all what I did, I wish I knew what specific thing made it work, literally all I did was re-extracted the zip with Xcode 8 and dragged it to my Applications folder, I still have 7.3 installed as well. I also cleared the DerivedData folder, not sure if that did anything though. And I made sure the command line tools were set to Xcode 8.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression in macOS Sierra that multiple developers have reported in the forums and in the lab sessions at WWDC.  Xcode 7.3 is not officially supported on Sierra.  If you want to use macOS Sierra, please use Xcode 8.0 beta or later.

If you must use Xcode 7.3 on Sierra, you can partially workaround this bug by using Xcode.app to install the app through Build & Run, launch the app suspended from the command line (`xcrun simctl launch -w booted <app identifier>`) and then attach with the debugger and resume the suspended process.

Note that this issue only impact Xcode 7.3.1 downloaded from the Mac App Store.  You will not hit this issue if you use Xcode downloaded from http://developer.apple.com (ie, the "drag & drop installer").  Note that you *might* hit another issue with the same symptoms when using the drag & drop installer.  That is discussed in [DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200318/dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-dtxconnection-with-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

If you have reinstalled CocoaPods so that it updated from a version that is lower than 1.0.0 to 1.0.0 or above it can't hurt to delete your DerivedData folder of the project that is having problems. I don't know why it fixes a lot of bugs when above scenario is the case, but it does! You can do this by going to: Window -> Projects

[image: Select projects]

Then select your project on the left (It was my "Piece" project for me)

[image]

Then click the delete button

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Launch "Keychain Access", go to "Preferences..." and click "Reset My Default Keychain". After that I was finally able to build my projects.