# DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator - mac os sierra

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-sierra

I know this is duplicate question.
[DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200318/dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-dtxconnection-with-simulator)

But I did not found any solutions. Thats why I am asking again. I install the MacOS sierra and I install XCODE 8. In my mac I have xcode 7 and xcode8. But when I open the xcode 7 and when I run the code I am getting above error  message.

> DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator

But If I run the code in xcode 8 it is working.

What is the issue here?

NOTE:

1. Clean build, derivedata clear, Kill the xcode, kill the simulator restart mac those solutions are not working.
2. I have two mac. I checked with two macs. Both are having same issue

Comment: This should not be closed. It is not a duplicate. SO community will eventually realize their mistake when this question blows up when developers start to test the ios10B1 release train.

Comment: Force quite my simulator and it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Fast fix:**

- Build app
- The app will still install on the simulator, even with the error
- Launch the app manually on the simulator
- Go to Xcode
- Click Debug > Attach to Process > Your App Name

This isn't really a "fast fix" since you have to do it every time you want to run your app.

---

**Slower, but better, fix:**

Reinstall Xcode from the Developer Center ("Other Downloads" page, thanks @milesper). Doing so will clear this error, and the app will run smoothly.

Comment: Thanks, you make my day.

Comment: Doesn't the link in the Developer Center just go to the Mac App Store?  Is there some other way to download?

Comment: @milesper No, the Developer Center has a direct download.

Comment: @ShaanSingh I found it but you have to go to the "other downloads" page

Comment: @milesper Updated answer, thanks.