# Error while running iOS Application on Simulator with Xcode 7.3.1 on macOS 10.12 (beta 1)

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently updated my mac to macOS 10.12 (beta 1) but since, I'm not able to run any apps in the simulator.

On every attempt I'm getting the error message: 
***DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator.***

I don't understand why I have this error.

I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200318/dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-dtxconnection-with-simulator) and I tried to restart my mac, clean the derived data of Xcode, update the Command Line Tool, wait processing but nothing worked...

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200318/dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-dtxconnection-with-simulator)?

Comment: Yes, but none of them solutions are working

Comment: OK, voted to re-open.